# Ionic 5 app on android device unable to connect to localhost

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I successfully run my ionic app on a real Android device but I always cannot connect the app to the local backend server, I tried this command

```
ionic capacitor run android --external
```

i got this output

```
[capacitor] ✖ Running Gradle build - failed!
[capacitor] [error] ERR_SUBPROCESS_COMMAND_NOT_FOUND
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
```

is there any solutions to connect from the android device to my localhost ?